# Bootstrap datepicker always pops up top of asp.net textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datepicker

Good day Programmers,

I have this asp.net textbox I have attached Bootstrap Datepicker to. The datepicker works fine on that it pops up on top of the textbox even after it has been instructed to pop up under the text box. See Picture below. I have pulled all my hair and have become bald of a sudden.

Also, I have included my markup. Thanks in advance.

Jquery script:

```
function pageLoad() {
       $("#<% =txtDate.ClientID%>").datepicker({
       //$('.input-group').datepicker({
       //$('#txtDate').datepicker({
           autoclose: true,
           todayHighlight: true,
           format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
           todayBtn: "linked",
           orientation: "bottom auto"
       });
   };
```

HTML Markup:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
            <div  runat="server" ID="hid1" visible="false">
            <h4> Add Absences</h4>
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label" runat="server" Text="Absence Date"></asp:Label>
                <div class="col-md-5 input-group date">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
                    <%--<span class="input-group-addon">--%>
                                <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                           <%-- </span>--%>

                </div>

                &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp;
                <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" CssClass="btn btn-success" />
            </div> </div>
```

Result:

[image: See the image here]

You will also notice the pop up goes under the navigation menu.

.

Comment: Is there enough space at the bottom? I think it'll try to open in the direction where there is sufficient space for it to show.

Comment: Yes there is, I did not constraint the height of the divs.